# Unable to shutdown Ubuntu 18.04 guest using virsh-shutdown

Tags: ubuntu, kvm, shutdown, virsh

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 (desktop) in a VM using Debian 9 and KVM as the hypervisor but running `virsh shutdown BS-MS01` I get a message saying the domain is shutting down but the VM is actually still sat on the login screen.

I have confirmed `acpid` is installed and running on the guest:

```
ms01admin@BS-MS01:~$ sudo service acpid status
● acpid.service - ACPI event daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/acpid.service; disabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-02-16 20:33:52 GMT; 2h 17min ago
 Main PID: 716 (acpid)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4614)
   CGroup: /system.slice/acpid.service
           └─716 /usr/sbin/acpid
```

The VM has been created with `</acpi>` in the xml too:

```
<domain type='kvm' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
  <name>BS-MS01</name>
  <uuid>8e94c247-bf28-455f-bdee-c64f0a1c9404</uuid>
  <title>BS-MS01</title>
  <description>Main media server.</description>
  <memory unit='KiB'>4194304</memory>
  <currentMemory unit='KiB'>4194304</currentMemory>
  <vcpu placement='static'>8</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-q35-2.8'>hvm</type>
    <loader readonly='yes' type='pflash'>/usr/share/OVMF/OVMF_CODE.fd</loader>
    <nvram>/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/nvram/BS-MS01_VARS.fd</nvram>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <bootmenu enable='no'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
    <apic/>
    <vmport state='off'/>
  </features>
  <cpu mode='custom' match='exact'>
    <model fallback='allow'>Haswell-noTSX</model>
  </cpu>
  <clock offset='utc'>
    <timer name='rtc' tickpolicy='catchup'/>
    <timer name='pit' tickpolicy='delay'/>
    <timer name='hpet' present='no'/>
  </clock>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <pm>
    <suspend-to-mem enabled='no'/>
    <suspend-to-disk enabled='no'/>
  </pm>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='qcow2'/>
      <source file='/storage/vm/hdd/bsms01.qcow2'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x05' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <target dev='sda' bus='sata'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <controller type='usb' index='0' model='nec-xhci'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x04' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='sata' index='0'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1f' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='0' model='pcie-root'/>
    <controller type='pci' index='1' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='ioh3420'/>
      <target chassis='1' port='0x8'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x0' multifunction='on'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='2' model='dmi-to-pci-bridge'>
      <model name='i82801b11-bridge'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x1e' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='3' model='pci-bridge'>
      <model name='pci-bridge'/>
      <target chassisNr='3'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x02' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='4' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='ioh3420'/>
      <target chassis='4' port='0x9'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x1'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='5' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='ioh3420'/>
      <target chassis='5' port='0xa'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x2'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='6' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='ioh3420'/>
      <target chassis='6' port='0xb'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x3'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='7' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='ioh3420'/>
      <target chassis='7' port='0xc'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x4'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='8' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='ioh3420'/>
      <target chassis='8' port='0xd'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x5'/>
    </controller>
    <controller type='pci' index='9' model='pcie-root-port'>
      <model name='ioh3420'/>
      <target chassis='9' port='0xe'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x01' function='0x6'/>
    </controller>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:40:b9:20'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <input type='keyboard' bus='ps2'/>
    <sound model='ich6'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x01' function='0x0'/>
    </sound>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x06' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <hostdev mode='subsystem' type='pci' managed='yes'>
      <source>
        <address domain='0x0000' bus='0x03' slot='0x00' function='0x1'/>
      </source>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x07' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </hostdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='1'/>
   </redirdev>
    <redirdev bus='usb' type='spicevmc'>
      <address type='usb' bus='0' port='2'/>
    </redirdev>
    <memballoon model='virtio'>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x08' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </memballoon>
  </devices>
  <qemu:commandline>
    <qemu:arg value='-cpu'/>
    <qemu:arg value='host,hv_time,kvm=off,hv_vendor_id=null'/>
  </qemu:commandline>
</domain>
```

I've even added `acpi=force` to grub but have not had any luck getting it to work and I've run out of ideas.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Also just to clarify I have other guests (Windows and Linux) that are shutting down correctly, so I think you might be right about the HW configuration.

Comment: Looks like you passed through a couple of PCI devices, at least one of which is a video card? That might have something to do with it. I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop VM in virt-manager, and it shuts down properly from `virsh shutdown` or virt-manager. You might try re-creating the VM.

Comment: That's correct, it's the GFX card and it's counterpart sound device. This was happening before I passed these through though :( I've found the solution though which I posted below for future reference :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like an event for the power button wasn't created automatically, not sure why?

Created a new event handler here:
`sudo nano /etc/acpi/events/powerbtn`

With these parameters:

```
event=button/power
action=/sbin/poweroff
```

Then restarted the service:
`sudo service acpid restart`

Now I'm able to shutdown the guest!

Comment: That's a nice workaround. Though by default you can still shutdown the guest even if acpid isn't running - or even not installed! So something else is still wrong.

Comment: Something is definitely odd, it's been doing it since day 1 of it being installed and I'm not sure why, I have a tonne of other VM's and all of them worked without any faffing. It was actually while poking around in the acpi directory of another guest I noticed there was a `button/power` event handler so I just recreated it...oh well everything's working for now. Hopefully no other issues rear their ugly head. :P

Comment: Old pre-systemd distros needed acpid in order to shutdown properly (and respond to other events). I'm not exactly sure why it's even shipped anymore, but oh well.

Comment: This solution works as well to ubuntu 20.04 vm. I applied it to a vm I recently created that wasn't going shutdown after virsh command was executed. Now it works flawlessly.